# variable might not have been defined

Tags: php

Есть следующий код:

```
if (is_array($data["members"])) {
       foreach ($data["members"] as $key => $member) {
                $dataMembers[] = $member;
       }
       $dataMembers = json_encode($dataMembers);
}
```

PhpStorm выдает подсказку что переменная может быть не задана на предпоследней строке. Не хотелось бы допустить ошибок, но вроде бы такого не должно быть.

Добавил еще проверку чтобы $data["members"] был не empty, но переменная все еще подчеркнута. Что-то упускаю?

Ps. Смысл в том, чтобы в конце получить строку вида ["x1","x2" ... "xn"]. Без этого перебора иногда записывает так {"1":"x1","2":"x2"..."n":"xn"} из-за чего после json_decode я получаю объект вместо массива.

Comment: Напишите полный код вашей функции (метода). По такому кусочку невозможно что-либо сказать.

Comment: перед циклом поставь `$dataMembers = []` и твое подчеркивание переменной пропадет.

Comment: вместо foreach `$dataMembers = json_encode(array_values($dataMembers));